# R: Combine multiple records over multiple columns

Tags: r, grouping, tidyverse

I have data with multiple records for each participant (the number of records varies).  I'm trying to combine these records into one for each participant by combining each column's records forthat participant.

So, if I have data like:

```
dummy<-tribble(
  ~id, ~A, ~B, ~C, ~D,
  1, "one", "two", "three", "four",
  1, "one", "two", "three", "five",
  1, "one", "six", "three", "four",
  1, "one", "seven", "three", "five",
  2, "one", "two", "three", "four",
  2, "one", "two", "six", "five",
  3, "one", "two", "three", "four",
  3, "one", "seven", "six", "five",
  3, "one", "two", "six", "eight"
)
```

I'm looking for output like:

```
1, "one+one+one+one", "two+two+six+seven", "three+three+three+three", "four+five+four+five",
2, "one+one", "two+two", "three+six", "four+five",
3, "one+one+one", "two+seven+two", "three+six+six", "four+five+eight",
```

I'd prefer to use `tidyverse`, and I feel that `group_by` and `unite` would come in here somewhere, but I haven't a clue as to how to loop through the varying number of records for each participant, and apply that over all the columns (there are 28 in the real data).

Ideally, I'd also then want to discard repeated data, so that I get:

```
1, "one", "two+two+six+seven", "three+three+three+three", "four+five+four+five",
2, "one", "two", "three+six", "four+five",
3, "one", "two+seven+two", "three+six+six", "four+five+eight",
```

Any suggestions on how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `str_c`

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
dummy %>%
    group_by(id) %>%
    summarise(across(A:D,  ~str_c(unique(.), collapse = "+")))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 3 x 5
     id A     B             C         D              
  <dbl> <chr> <chr>         <chr>     <chr>          
1     1 one   two+six+seven three     four+five      
2     2 one   two           three+six four+five      
3     3 one   two+seven     three+six four+five+eight
```

Comment: Gee, guys - thank you SO much.  I didn't think this could be done in just one line of code besides the group_by.  So cool.  Since akrun was first by a few minutes, I've accepted his answer.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

`group_by()` and `summarise()` would do. `unique()` removes the repeated data.

```
dummy %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  summarise(across(A:D, ~ paste(unique(.), collapse = "+")))

# # A tibble: 3 x 5
#      id A     B             C         D
#   <dbl> <chr> <chr>         <chr>     <chr>
# 1     1 one   two+six+seven three     four+five      
# 2     2 one   two           three+six four+five      
# 3     3 one   two+seven     three+six four+five+eight
```

Answer (score 0):

For first output you may also do

```r
library(tidyverse)

dummy<-tribble(
  ~id, ~A, ~B, ~C, ~D,
  1, "one", "two", "three", "four",
  1, "one", "two", "three", "five",
  1, "one", "six", "three", "four",
  1, "one", "seven", "three", "five",
  2, "one", "two", "three", "four",
  2, "one", "two", "six", "five",
  3, "one", "two", "three", "four",
  3, "one", "seven", "six", "five",
  3, "one", "two", "six", "eight"
)

dummy %>% group_by(id) %>%
  summarise(across(everything(), ~paste(., collapse = '+')))
#> # A tibble: 3 x 5
#>      id A               B                C                     D                
#>   <dbl> <chr>           <chr>            <chr>                 <chr>            
#> 1     1 one+one+one+one two+two+six+sev~ three+three+three+th~ four+five+four+f~
#> 2     2 one+one         two+two          three+six             four+five        
#> 3     3 one+one+one     two+seven+two    three+six+six         four+five+eight
```

<sup>Created on 2021-06-28 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>